# Google Directory API gives 401 with Service Account just for ADMIN_DIRECTORY_ORGUNIT

Tags: java, oauth

I'm trying to use some data about the members of our G Suite Business account in a Java/Spring project. I set up the domain wide delegation for a service account with the apropriate "Directory" API and getting the users data works like charm - but when requesting the orgUnits data i always get "401 Unauthorized" error.

It doesn't matter if i use "readonly" or not and it also works with "DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP".

```java
private Directory getDirectoryService(String type) {
    //ommit some variables...
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
        .setServiceAccountUser(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH))
        .build();

    return new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
        .build();
}

//works
Users users = getDirectoryService(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER).users()
    .list()
    .setCustomer(CUSTOMER_ID)
    .execute();

//401
OrgUnits units = getDirectoryService(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_ORGUNIT).orgunits()
    .list("")
    .setCustomerId(CUSTOMER_ID)
    .execute();
```

First call works, but second gives error:
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this same issue when trying to use the Admin SDK Google API with a service account.

The issue was occurring for me because the Scopes that were set in my code did not match those set at my Google Admin Console under "Security > Advanced Settings > Manage API client access". Once these were aligned it all started working perfectly.

Comment: Well - you are right! Perhaps i was a bit tired after several tries with this issue and missed out "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit" accidentially.